# Split the sentence into its tokens as a character annotation Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, python-re

After a long search I didn't find any answer to my question that is why I decided to put my question here. I am trying to achive some specific result with RE and NLTK. 
Given a sentence, on each character I have to use the `BIS` format, that is, tagging each character as `B (beginning of the token)`, `I (intermediate or end position of the token)`, `S for space`. 
For instance, given the sentence:

> The pen is on the table.

The system will have to provide the following output:

```
BIISBIISBISBISBIISBIIIIB
```

which can be read as:

```
<3-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <5-char token> <1-char token>)
```

My result is kinda close but instead of:

```
BIISBIISBISBISBIISBIIIIB
```

I get:

```
BIISBIISBISBISBIISBIIIISB
```

Meaning I get space between `table` and dot `.`
The output should be:

```
<3-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <5-char token> <1-char token>
```

Mine is :

```
<3-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <2-char token> <space> <3-char token> <space> <5-char token> <space> <1-char token>
```

My code so far:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re
p = "The pen is on the table."
# Split text into words using NLTK
text = word_tokenize(p)
print(text)
initial_char = [x.replace(x[0],'B') for x in text]
print(initial_char)
def listToString(s):  
    # initialize an empty string 
    str1 = " " 
    # return string   
    return (str1.join(s)) 
new = listToString(initial_char)
print(new)
def start_from_sec(my_text):
    return ' '.join([f'{word[0]}{(len(word) - 1) * "I"}' for word in my_text.split()])
res = start_from_sec(new)
p = re.sub(' ', 'S', res)
print(p)
```

Comment: Please see my approach. I am not providing all possible alternatives, you need to come up with more precise specifications/examples first. Feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Is there any way to achieve it using nltk tokenizer?

Comment: I do not think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a single regex to tokenize the string:

```
(\w)(\w*)|([^\w\s])|\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g0iXw1/1)

**Pattern details**

- `(\w)(\w*)` - Group 1: any word char (letter, digit or `_`) and then Group 2: any 0 or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `([^\w\s])`  - Group 3: any char but a word and whitespace char
- `|` - or
- `\s` - a whitespace char

If Group 1 matches, the return value is `B` + the same number of `I`s as the number of chars in Group 2. If Group 3 matches, replace with `B`. Else, a whitespace is matched, replace with `S`.

This can be customized further, e.g.

- Treat `_` only as punctuation: `r'([^\W_])([^\W_]*)|([^\w\s]|_)|\s'`
- Replace 1 or more whitespaces with a single `S`: `r'([^\W_])([^\W_]*)|([^\w\s]|_)|\s+'`

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/GOOLNJ):

```
import re
p = "The pen is on the table."
def repl(x):
    if x.group(1):
        return "B{}".format("I"*len(x.group(2)))
    elif x.group(3):
        return "B"
    else:
        return "S"

print( re.sub(r'(\w)(\w*)|([^\w\s])|\s', repl, p) )
# => BIISBIISBISBISBIISBIIIIB
```